# Finding transfer function from Bode plot

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, bode-plot, system

While I know how to find the transfer function from the response graph, I don't know
how to find it from Bode plot.

What I know about the system:

1. The system is a second order system
2. The system has no zeros
3. According to the Bode plot, I estimate that there is a double pole at w=2.5

[image]

therefore, I need to find Wn, zeta and K.

This is the graph:
[image]

You can ignore the noise in the end of the phase graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a 2nd-order low-pass filter you can use this to calculate what the damping ratio, (\$\zeta\$) is: -

[image]
Image from [my basic website](http://www.stades.co.uk/).

Look at the peaking frequency in **your** spectrum and calculate the damping ratio from that. It looks like "k" the gain coefficient is unity (because of the low frequency gain aligning with 0 dB on your picture) so this needn't play a part anymore.

Once you have the damping ratio you can calculate what \$\omega_n\$ (also referred to as \$\omega_0\$) is.

It looks like you have about 8 dB of peaking. That's a ratio of 2.512. So solve the peaking amplitude formula to find \$\zeta\$. I estimate \$\zeta\$ to be about 0.2050.

I estimate the peak position in the spectrum to be at about 0.957053 of the natural resonant frequency, \$\omega_n\$.

Of course you could work a little bit on the graph to find the same answers: -

[image]